# Disable IIS7 Pool recycling from ASP.NET config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is it possible to disable IIS7 Pool recycling from ASP.NET application using web.config file?

Comment: Have you done some intial research on this topic? Please google and do your home work before posting it on stack overflow.

Comment: @Tomas, it would help if you can explain why you need to disable app pool recycle!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's not possible. True - it (Application Pool Recycling) can be controlled using configuration file but not at the application level but only at server level using ApplicationHost.config - see the [documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling).

Controlling at application level does not make sense because a single application pool may support multiple web applications (and hence there could be conflicting configuration).